# Meaning of "they were become traditional"

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

From Byron's *[Don Juan](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron)/Canto_the_First):*

> And if your quarrels should rip up old stories,
>        And help them with a lie or two additional,
>   I'm not to blame, as you well know—no more is
>        Any one else—**they were become traditional**;
>   Besides, their resurrection aids our glories
>        By contrast, which is what we just were wishing all:
>   And science profits by this resurrection—
>   Dead scandals form good subjects for dissection.

What became traditional - stories or "any one else"? And what does that mean? Since the stories are so old, they have become traditional, which means they are passed from generation to generation by tradition?

I can't wrap my mind around this. I'm not asking for literary criticism, just the basic description of what is being told here.

As an aside, does "were become" mean "had become"? Is it in line with early 19th century grammar?

Comment: Yes, sometimes *be* was formerly used instead of *have*  to form perfects with intransitive verbs in English as with so many of our cousin languages: *Now that Midwinter **is come and gone***.

Comment: You really can't wrestle this critter without getting into the literary stuff. Simply, the antecedent of "they" is stories, but it's not a simple picture. Byron digresses the way modern politicians tweet - incessantly and, IMO,  incorrigibly. It's hard to say who *is* to blame without mucking into the poem, although a safe bet in *Don Juan* is Wordsworth and/or Coleridge. Cheers!